# Disabling fried nVidia GPU on ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have an ASUS laptop (ROG GL552VW) with a GTX 960M. The gtx is fried and causes some problem with my installation (freezing for 2 minute at startup and when shutting off).

I would like to completely disable the card and any drivers associated with but can't find a way to do it properly...

I've tried to do it via BIOS like I did with an older laptop but it is not possible with this model.

I have 2 questions about this :

- How can I disable it on this install ?
- Is it possible to disable it during Ubuntu install so it's never seen by Ubuntu at all ?

PS : I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so please pardon me if my question is dumb

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this before it freezes:

- At the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to enter TTY mode
- Enter your login credentials.
- Enter this command:

  ```
  sudo prime-select intel
  ```

  and you will be asked for your password again.
- Reboot the computer:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

With some luck, this should help.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this it says to me "prime-select: command not found"

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? The Nvidia drivers are listed as installed in the `Softwares & Updates > Additional Drivers` configuration window? 

If the drivers are not installed, try installing them (a little guide [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu)), then try my answer again